# Use AFNetworking to create a parse.com pointer object through REST API

Tags: ios, rest, parse-platform, afnetworking

I'm trying to use AFNetworking to call the parse.com REST API.
GET-Requests are working quite well so far. But when it comes to object creation I have a problem creating relations (pointers to object-ids) between two parse objects.

What I've tried so far:

```
NSString* parameterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"__op\":\"AddRelation\",\"objects\":[{\"__type\":\"Pointer\",\"className\":\"MyClass\",\"objectId\":\"%@\"}]}", myClassObjectId];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"myClass": parameterString};

[self.manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { ... }];
```

Creating objects without pointers works well too. I think the error is related to my `parameterString` syntax:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)","code":111,"error":"invalid type for key myClass, expected *MyClass, but got string"
```

Any ideas? Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, finally:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"myClass":@{@"__type":@"Pointer", @"className":@"MyClass", @"objectId":[foobar objectID]}};
[self.manager POST:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { ... }];
```

so... just plain JSON.